# Adding variables to ChallengeSchema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I tried adding likes/dislikes/satisfaction variables to my challengemodel, but when I look into my database (Atlas MongoDB) I can only see the ones that where there initially (title, description).

My database has a collection "challenges" with 4 challenges with the below structure (not likes/dislikes/satisfaction). How do I also include likes/dislikes/satisfaction with their default 0 value in here?--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
  QUERY RESULTS 1-4 OF 4
    _id:5eb98c06a1f08159842b430d
    title:"aaaaaaa"
    description:"aaaaaaaaa"
    __v:0
```

---

```
const challengeSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    initiator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User"},
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    dislikes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    satisfaction: { type: Number, default: 0 }
})
```

---

```
//add challenge
router.post("/startchallenge", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .create({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    likes: req.body.likes,
    dislikes: req.body.dislikes,
    satisfaction: req.body.satisfaction
  })
  .then((response) => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is design in such way you manipulate document and a document is just a view of your data, you have to update every document already present in your collection manually if you want all your document having the same structure.

If you have such problem in your application, you probably need to switch on SQL, which carry easily those issue with other tradeoff of course.

Comment: can you please clarify? I don't understand